# Condition to select WHICH table - SQL or SQLITE

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have created the following tables:

Customer table:

```
flag    |   cust_id |   customer
--------------------------------
1       |   60      |   customer1
0       |   61      |   customer2
0       |   62      |   customer3
```

Accounts table:

```
acc_id  |   cust_id |   account_name
------------------------------------
1       |   62      |   account1
2       |   63      |   account2
3       |   62      |   account3
4       |   62      |   account4
```

Contacts table:

```
con_id  |   cust_id |   contact_name
------------------------------------
1       |   60      |   contact1
2       |   60      |   contact2
3       |   61      |   contact3
4       |   62      |   contact4
```

I need the data by using the following condition if `flag ==1` from Customer table then I need all the rows from Accounts table else `flag==0` then I need all the rows from Contacts table.

How to achieve this in one statement?

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: It seems to me that you want the UNION of two JOINs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need the UNION of 2 JOINs.
Something like:

```
-- SELECT the items from Customer and Accounts WHERE flag = 1
SELECT Customer.customer, Accounts.account_name AS Name FROM Customer 
INNER JOIN Accounts ON Customer.cust_id = Accounts.cust_id 
WHERE Customer.flag = 1 
-- MERGE the 2 queries WITHOUT duplicates (use UNION ALL if you want the duplicates)
UNION 
-- SELECT the items from Customer and Contacts WHERE flag = 0
SELECT Customer.customer, Contacts.contacts_name AS Name FROM Customer 
INNER JOIN Contacts ON Customer.cust_id = Contacts.cust_id 
WHERE Customer.flag = 0
```

You might want to add Customer.cust_id to both your query column lists.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Golem. After modifying some conditions in the query i got the solution. Thanks once again.